# Magento 2 products bulk import is should come to child categories is same or not?

Tags: magento2.2

```
magento 2 in using producs bulk import if child categories same or not?

I have  below attached my excel files 


IRW4205     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 8MM 10502804        1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 40.6                irw_4205                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4210     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 10MM 10502805       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 38.5                irw_4210                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4215     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 12MM 10502806       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 38.5                irw_4215                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4220     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Use in electric hand drill or drill press</li><li>Fast cutting</li><li>Superior to flat bits</li><li>5 MM double groove</li><li>Hex shank</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 13MM 10502807       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35              irw_4220                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4225     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 14MM 10502808       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 37.1                irw_4225                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4230     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 16MM 10502809       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35.7                irw_4230                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4235     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 18MM 10502811       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35              irw_4235                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4245     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 20MM 10502813       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35.7                irw_4245                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4250     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 22MM 10502814       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35.7                irw_4250                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4255     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 24MM 10502815       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35              irw_4255                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4260     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 25MM 10502816       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 35.7                irw_4260                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4265     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 28MM 10502818       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 46.2                irw_4265                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4270     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 30MM 10502819       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 49              irw_4270                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4275     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 32MM 10502820       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 46.9                irw_4275                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4280     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 35MM 10502821       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 47.6                irw_4280                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4285     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 38MM 10502822       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 49              irw_4285                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
IRW4290     SW Flat Bits    simple  Default Category/Tools,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories,Default Category/Tools/Drill Bits, Taps & Threading Dies/Drill Bits, Sets & Accessories/Flat Bits       Flat Bit    <ul><li>Patented groove point and cutting edge cutting edges cut (does not scrape) the wood4x faster</li><li>Parabolic scoop for control & removal of wood chips</li><li>Increased relief angle from12 to 17</li><li>10 larger shank for added durability</li></ul> SPEEDBLU IRWIN BIT FLAT 40MM 10502823       1   Taxable Goods   Catalog, Search 46.9                irw_4290                                Block after Info Column             Use config                                  1000    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   10000   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

magento 2 in bulk import allowed in child category same.
[image]